# How to import material web component to svelte project

Tags: web, frontend, svelte

I'm new to svelte and having some problem to import [material web](https://github.com/material-components/material-web) component to svelte project.

First it seems works fine when project first run with imported components (like tabs,buttons... )

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import '@material/web/all';

    $: tabIndex = 0;
  

    function handleChange(event: any) {
        tabIndex = event.target.activeTabIndex;
    }
</script>

<div>
    <md-tabs on:change={handleChange}>
        <md-primary-tab active={tabIndex == 0}>A</md-primary-tab>
        <md-primary-tab active={tabIndex == 1}>B</md-primary-tab>
        <md-primary-tab active={tabIndex == 2}>C</md-primary-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</div>
```

But those components cannot receive DOM event at on:{eventname} keywords.

Other svelte components (like [svelte material ui](https://sveltematerialui.com/)) works fine.

Is there any misunderstands about svelte? or vanilla js components(material web) just cannot use svelte? if then, is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I self-found solution in [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/faq#integrations-how-do-i-use-a-client-side-only-library-that-depends-on-document-or-window)

in the `/routes/layout.svelte`

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { browser } from '$app/environment';

    const MaterialWebTabComponent = browser ? import('@material/web/all') : new Promise(() => {});

    $: tabIndex = 0;

    async function handleChange(event: any) {
        tabIndex = event.target.activeTabIndex;
    }
</script>
{#await MaterialWebTabComponent}
    <p>Loading...</p>
{:then component}
    <div>
        <md-tabs on:change={handleChange}>
            <md-primary-tab active={tabIndex === 0}>A</md-primary-tab>
            <md-primary-tab active={tabIndex === 1}>B</md-primary-tab>
            <md-primary-tab active={tabIndex === 2}>C</md-primary-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </div>
{:catch error}
    <p>Something went wrong: {error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

cause of CSR(Client-Side rendering).